# Custom wordpress admin page/url "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Here's a custom wordpress admin page I created:-

```
// code located in my custom plugin's php file

function my_special_function(){

    echo '<div> Hello World </div>';

}

function my_menu_page(){

    $page_title = "Hello Page Title";
    $menu_title = "Hello Menu Title";
    $capability = "administrator";
    $menu_slug = "do_something";
    $function = my_special_function;
    add_menu_page($page_title,  $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_page');
```

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page , this function takes a 'capability' (see Roles and Capabilities) which will be used to determine whether or not a page is included in the menu. The function which is hooked in to handle the output of the page must check that the user has the required 'capability' as well.

The current user I am using is the administrator, but when I attempt to access the page

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin.php?page=do_something
```

I get

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

Why's that so? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
function my_special_function(){
    ?>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <!-- ALL THE CUSTOM MARK UP SHOULD BE INSIDE WRAP-->
        </div>
    <?php
}

function my_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page('Page title', 'Menu Title', 'administrator', 'page_slug', 'my_special_function');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_page');
```

Try this!

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't it. I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Any luck? I tried it locally, works neat.

Comment: What version of wordpress are you using? Perhaps my version 3.2.2 has a problem with `administrator` rights? Or there's something specific I need to configure for my administrators? My remote site and local site are both having the same error.

Comment: I'm using the latest version bro! And the code is totally version independent!

Comment: You shouldn't use role names in place of capabilities. The permissions an 'administrator' has can be changed. See @fischi's answer.

Comment: Yes, I read that part of the docs, tried using "manage_options" and "read" and a variety of other possible values; but no matter, having exactly the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

try using the needed capability, not the user role. note that these are two different items - a role can have capabilities, but a administrator role does not necessarily include any capabilities, as they are free to be assigned and removed.

`manage_options` would be a good capability for you to start with.

```
function my_special_function(){
    ?>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
            <!-- ALL THE CUSTOM MARK UP SHOULD BE INSIDE WRAP-->
        </div>
    <?php
}

function my_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page('Page title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'page_slug', 'my_special_function');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_page');
```

Comment: I also tried that and that does not work either.

Comment: are you sure your user has the capability to 'manage_options'? if you are not sure, try 'read_posts', it is a very lowkey capability.

Comment: If I use `read_posts`, the menu doesn't even show up on the admin side bar. I tried `read` again (tried previously) - same error.

Comment: So to rephrase my question a little - how/where can I find out the current `capability` of my current user? I just know that my current user is listed as an Administrator in the "users list" page.

Comment: i am sorry, the capability would be 'read'

Comment: your user has a few capabilities - they are combined in a role. for example, you can have read, update_core, delete_private_posts and many many more in one role. as the roles are not fixed, you can manipulate the default wordpress settings and assign new capabilities to new roles, or remove them.

Comment: Yes, I read this part about how capabilities can be assigned and removed in the docs. BUT... where do I find this code??

Comment: easiest way is to install Capability Manager - you can check and modify your roles and capabilities there.